# sympy positive Deferred Vector

Tags: sympy

Can you declared a  Deferred Vector as only containing positive values?

I need to take the derivative of an expression short of like this:

```
exp = sym.cosh( (1/3)*sym.acosh( ((-3*abs(q))/(2*V[1])) * ((-3/V[1]))**(1/2) ) )
```

where V is a Deferred Vector with two variables that I want to make clear are positive, as when taking the derivative of exp I end up with both real and imaginary parts. If both numbers are positive, then the derivative is real.

I know how to declare variables to be positive, but can something be done with a vector?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like `DeferredVector` supports this, but [looking at the code](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/4ee682cb5e2c4c8a22359eebac33bdaf72fc0089/sympy/matrices/matrices.py#L66) it looks like

```
V = DeferredVector('V')
V[1]
```

is just a convenient way of writing

```
Symbol("V[1]")
```

so for your case I would just use symbols directly, which let you set assumptions on them.

You can get roughly the same thing by letting

```
V = symbols('V[0] V[1]', positive=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a workaround would be to declare an `epsilon` to be a real positive (small as you want) number to be added to the absolute value of `V`. Something like this:

```
epsilon = sym.symbols('epsilon', real=True, positive=True)
exp = sym.cosh( (1/3)*sym.acosh( ((-3*abs(q))/(2*(sym.Abs(V[1]) + epsilon))) * ((-3/(sym.Abs(V[1]) + epsilon)))**(1/2) ) )
```